# Programmatic creation of image button in cppwinrt

Tags: c++, c++-winrt

Using cppwinrt (standard C++, not C++/CX) how would you set the content of a Button to an image, programmatically? Has to be programmatically because cppwinrt does not yet support xaml, in which doing that is easy. Here's what I am trying, which results in a functional but empty button:

```
Button button = Button();
BitmapImage bitmapImage = BitmapImage();
Uri imageUri = Uri(L"ms-appx:///Assets/Images/stopbutton.png");
bitmapImage.UriSource(imageUri);
Image buttonImage = Image();
buttonImage.Height(30);
buttonImage.Width(30);
buttonImage.Source(bitmapImage);
button.Content(buttonImage);
```

Then of course I add the button, which does show up nicely, though blank. I've tried an absolute path for the .png, but that also fails. There must be a way to do this programmatically in C++.

Comment: Does the image actually exist in the location you specify? Try to debug through the code to see, if any of the operations fail, in particular those that load the image resource.

Comment: IInspectable, thanks. The image was indeed present at the specified location, but I had forgotten to use the Add Existing Item command to *add it to the project*.  Just dumb. Now the only problem is that it doesn't seem to be possible to make the image fill the entire button. Perhaps what I really need is an image that acts like a button,  not a button with an image.

Comment: In other words: The image resource *wasn't* at the specified location. A UWP application doesn't run from where it was compiled. The .appx package needs to be installed first, and any resources that aren't wrapped up in the package, won't be in the final installation.

Comment: Good point. Now if I can work a way to make a button that is all image, I'll be golden.

Comment: `Button button = Button();` `BitmapImage bitmapImage = BitmapImage();` `Image buttonImage = Image();` Stop doing this. It is not Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code works fine on my side. Just make sure that your image really is inside the Assets/Images folder, that you added it to your project and that it is copied with the app content during the build, by checking if the Content parameter in the image properties is set to True.

**Edit**
After reading your further requirements. Just set the button padding and border thickness to zero, this will remove any space around the image.

Here is a simple working application with your button creation code:

```
#include <winrt\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.h>


using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging;


struct App : ApplicationT<App>
{
    void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs const &)
    {
        Image image;
        image.Height(30);
        image.Width(30);
        image.Source(BitmapImage(Uri(L"ms-appx:///Assets/Images/sample.png")));

        Button button;
        button.Padding(ThicknessHelper::FromUniformLength(0));
        button.BorderThickness(ThicknessHelper::FromUniformLength(0));
        button.Content(image);

        Window window = Window::Current();
        window.Content(button);
        window.Activate();
    }

    static void Initialize(ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams const &)
    {
        make<App>();
    }

    static void Start()
    {
        Application::Start(App::Initialize);
    }
};

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)
{
    App::Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what is needed to make a button display an image that fills the button: rather than setting the button.Content to an image, create an ImageBrush with the image and set the button.Background to that ImageBrush, e.g.

```
Button button = Button();
button.Height(30);
button.Width(30);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = BitmapImage();
Uri imageUri = Uri(L"ms-appx:///Assets/Images/stopbutton.png");
bitmapImage.UriSource(imageUri);
ImageBrush imageBrush = ImageBrush();
imageBrush.ImageSource(bitmapImage);
button.Background(imageBrush);
//The button will now look exactly like the image.
```

Comment: That's an answer to a different question, not the one you asked. If you want to persist this answer, go ahead and ask a new question, and post the answer there.

Comment: But if I may comment on my own answer, there is yet another issue: when the cursor hovers over such an image button, it reverts to a default rectangle and hides the image. Some have said the way to fix that is to set the Content of the button to the same image as the Background (though using an Image, not an imageBrush). Trouble with that is that the image appears in miniature in the center of the button; so this is not entirely solved yet.

Comment: IInspectable, I see I have again broken the rules. Perhaps I can add another question in case anyone is interested.

Comment: The code you pasted here is not needed. Your original code works fine. See my answer.